# Scala Generics with Case Class and Object Companion

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I have this:

```
case class Aaa() extends NClass {
  def method1() = println("method1")
}

object Aaa extends NCompanion {
  def method2() = println("method2")
}
```

I would like to implement something like the following pseudo code:

```
abstract class Xxx[T] {
  // All the trash code of reflection/implicit should be in this class only
  instance = new T()
  companion = T
  instance.method1()
  companion.method2()
}
```

To use like this:

```
class Yyy extends Xxx[Aaa] {}
```

How can I implement this? It is better if I could use the new Scala Reflection API. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am trying to avoid replicated code in my unit tests. Why do you think this is a bad approach?

Comment: It's nice when you can trust types. `class X[T]` says I should be able to instantiate `X[T]` for any old `T`—not just `T` where `T` has a zero-argument constructor, etc.

Comment: In order to avoid reflection, when I do this kind of thing I would let `X` take a function as param that constructs `T`, i.e. `abstract class X[T](tConstructor: => T)` then `instance = tConstructor`.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am using a solution avoiding get the companion type with generics:

```
abstract class Xxx[T <: NClass[T], O <: NCompanion[T]](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) {
  def getInstance(): T
  def getCompanion(): O

  val classOfT = typeTag[T].mirror.runtimeClass(typeOf[T])
  val className = classOfT.getName
  println(s"$className")
  val t = getInstance()
  val manager = getCompanion()
}
```

Usage:

```
class Yyy extends Xxx[Aaa, Aaa.type] {
  override def getInstance: Aaa = {
    return new Aaa()
  }

  override def getCompanion: Aaa.type = {
    return Aaa
  }
}
```